# How to copy and paste a matrix from crossvalidated to the rstudio console (using clipboard)?

Tags: r, clipboard, copy-paste

The matrix is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   -1    0   -1   -1    0   -1
[2,]   -1    0   -1    1    1    0
[3,]   -1    0    1   -1    0    1
[4,]   -1    0    1    1   -1    0
[5,]    1   -1    0   -1    0    1
[6,]    1   -1    0    1   -1    0
[7,]    1    1    0   -1    0   -1
[8,]    1    1    0    1    1    0
```

I've tried several suggestions, including the closest to a successful try:

```
x <- readClipboard()

[1] "[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]"                     
[2] "+               [1,]   -1    0   -1   -1    0   -1"
[3] "+               [2,]   -1    0   -1    1    1    0"
[4] "+               [3,]   -1    0    1   -1    0    1"
[5] "+               [4,]   -1    0    1    1   -1    0"
[6] "+               [5,]    1   -1    0   -1    0    1"
[7] "+               [6,]    1   -1    0    1   -1    0"
[8] "+               [7,]    1    1    0   -1    0   -1"
[9] "+               [8,]    1    1    0    1    1    0"
```

which is not close to being ready to being useful.

I have seen `dput()`, and `dump()`, and `scan()`... all giving even worse results.

How can I paste from the clipboard this structure, and then move it to the R script for saving?

Comment: This is not exactly what you want but  I use `read.table(textConnection("paste in matrix"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `read.clipboard` from `library(psych)`

```
library(psych)
d1 <- read.clipboard()
d1
#     X..1. X..2. X..3. X..4. X..5. X..6.
#[1,]    -1     0    -1    -1     0    -1
#[2,]    -1     0    -1     1     1     0
#[3,]    -1     0     1    -1     0     1
#[4,]    -1     0     1     1    -1     0
#[5,]     1    -1     0    -1     0     1
#[6,]     1    -1     0     1    -1     0
#[7,]     1     1     0    -1     0    -1
#[8,]     1     1     0     1     1     0
```

The output will be a `data.frame` with `row.names` as  `"[1,]" "[2,]" "[3,]"`.  If needed, this can be changed.

```
row.names(d1) <- NULL
colnames(d1) <- gsub('[.]+', '', colnames(d1))
```

Comment: How do you move into the script?

Comment: @Toni Sorry, didn't get your comment.